# amqplib nodejs to consume rabbitmq

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqp

this is how i consume the queue in rabbit, i wonder why this promise still hangs and return no result. i am trying to hit an endpoint that call this promise and expect it to return just ok to make sure it gives me a 200 OK status. now it acts like it somehow does not get any return from this service, i wonder what i did wrong. thanks

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            try{    
                rabbit.then(conn => {               
                  return conn.createChannel();
                })
                .then(ch => {
                  let shit = ch.assertQueue(USER_LOG_QUEUE)
                  .then(ok => { 
                    if(ok.messageCount > 0){
                        return ch.consume(USER_LOG_QUEUE, function(msg) {
                            if (msg !== null) {                             
                                ch.ack(msg);
                                writeToFile(msg.content.toString())
                                .then(rs => {                                   
                                    console.log(rs);
                                })
                                .catch(err => reject(err));                             
                            }
                            console.log('finished');
                            ch.close();
                            resolve(ok);
                        })                      
                    }else{              
                        console.log('empty list : finished');                                                               
                        ch.close();
                        resolve(ok);
                    }                   
                })
                .then(ok => {
                    console.log('empty list2 : finished');              
                    resolve(ok)
                })
                .catch(err => reject(err));             
            }catch(err){                
                reject(err);
            }
        });
```